# Getting 404 on a MERN App deployed on heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, mern

I tried deploying my MERN stack app on Heroku but now I'm getting 404 when I try to launh the app. Log for the same are as follows :

```
2020-02-21T04:43:37.862088+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=task-reminder25.herokuapp.com request_id=d549deca-d280-4db4-8549-3579082e903c fwd="45.118.159.123" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=403 protocol=https
2020-02-21T04:43:37.862479+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.63.151.139 - - [21/Feb/2020:04:43:37 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 191 "https://dashboard.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"
```

I have added the Environment vaiables as well.
The content of my index.js(Backend) is:

```
//Serve static assets in production
if(process.env.NODE_ENV==='production') {
    //Set static folder
    app.use(express.static(`../client/build`));
    app.get('*',(req,res)=>{
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '..','client', 'build','index.html'))
    });

}
```

[image: Node]

It would be great if anyone could help me resolve this.
**Edit**: I have added the link to my Github repo if anyone would like to take a look at it.

Comment: https://github.com/nadaanbaalak/Task-Reminder-App The link to my Github Repo.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove nodemon if you have installed.

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js" // node your main file name
  },
```

Comment: But it is installed as a development Dependency, so it shouldn't matter as Dev Dependencies are pruned at the time of deployment. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Please remove  and check it. Nodemon will not work in Heroku as far as I know